# When does the ΔY-family of a simple graph contain multigraphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

Given a graph $G$, its [ΔY-family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%CE%94-_and_%CE%94Y-transformation#%CE%94Y-families) is the smallest family of graphs that contains $G$ and is closed under ΔY- and YΔ-transformations.

Since YΔ-transformations can introduce multi-edges, the ΔY-family of $G$ might consist of multigraphs even if $G$ itself is simple.
However, for many notable graph classes, this does not happen. For example, the [Petersen family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_family) is generated from $K_6$ and contains only simple graphs. The same is true for $K_7$. But it fails for $K_5$.

> **Question:** Is there a way to tell in advance whether $G$ generates a ΔY-family of only simple graphs?